# Basic Python exercise: Given a list of integers, if there is a repetition, place an '*'

Tags: python

Problem: Write a code in python that does the following: Given a list as an input, the output will be the same list but if there is a repetition, it will get replace it with a `'*'`.

For example, if input is `[1,2,3,4,4,5,4]`, then the output would be `[1,2,3,'*', '*', 5 , '*']`

Attempt: MY first approach was the following

```
c = [1,2,3,4,4,4,6,7]
d = [c[0]]
for i in range(len(c)-1):
    if c[i+1]==c[i]:
        c[i+1]= '*'

    d.append(c[i+1])

print(d)
```

But, clearly, this does not work. Now, I am trying to come up with ideas as to how to solve such a problem. Im new to python so Im trying to figure out. will a while loop work here?

Comment: Your code only checks for contiguous repeats. A simple way to do this task would be to count the occurences of each number first, then iterate over the list again and replace the repeating elements with a `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to replace contiguous repeats (e.g. `[1, 1]` and `[1, 1, 0, 1]` but not `[1, 0, 1]`), you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) then check the lengths of the groups.

```
from itertools import groupby

def replace_repeats_with_stars(list_in):
    """
    >>> replace_repeats_with_stars([1, 1])
    ['*', '*']
    >>> replace_repeats_with_stars([1, 1, 0, 1])
    ['*', '*', 0, '*']
    >>> replace_repeats_with_stars([1, 0, 1])
    [1, 0, 1]
    """
    repeats = {k for k, g in groupby(list_in) if len(list(g)) > 1}
    return ['*' if x in repeats else x for x in list_in]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrence of each number and then replace the one's that occur more than once with `*`.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4]
>>> count = Counter(c)
>>> d = [x if count[x] == 1 else '*' for x in c]
>>> d
[1, 2, 3, '*', '*', 5, '*']
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you need:

```
c = [1,2,3,4,4,4,6,7,6]

dup_c = []
for idx,i in enumerate(c):
    if i in dup_c:
        c[idx] = "*"
    else:
        dup_c.append(i)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '*', 6, 7, '*']
```

Comment: This doesn't work with OP's first example: `[1,2,3,4,4,5,4]` -> `[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', 5, '*']`

Comment: @Akshay No I mean OP's desired output for the first example, `[1,2,3,4,4,5,4]`, is `[1,2,3,'*', '*', 5 , '*']`, but this keeps the first `4`.

Comment: @wjandrea The accepted answer gives the same output, Let OP clarify before I edit my answer

Comment: @Akshay Yeah I'm confused. Seems like OP doesn't have their requirements straight.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below approach in python.

```py
>>> c = [1,2,3,4,4,4,6,7]
>>> new_c = []
>>> for index,value in enumerate(c):
    if value in new_c:
        new_c.append('x')
    else:
        new_c.append(value)

>>> new_c
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'x', 'x', 6, 7]
```

Agreeing with comment of @wjandrea, we dont need enumerate as we are not using index.

We can make it simpler as below:

```
>>> new_c = []
>>> for value in c:
    if value in new_c:
        new_c.append('x')
    else:
        new_c.append(value)
>>> new_c
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'x', 'x', 6, 7]
```

Comment: This doesn't work with OP's first example: `[1,2,3,4,4,5,4]` -> `[1, 2, 3, 4, 'x', 5, 'x']`. Also why do you use `enumerate` if you don't use `index`?

Comment: @wjandrea, It works with the first example also. I just tried.

Comment: I mean OP's expected output is `[1,2,3,'*', '*', 5 , '*']` but this keeps the first `4`. But OP's accepted this answer now, so I'm confused.

Comment: @wjandrea, sorry. got confused. I was thinking as replacing next instance

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
c = [1,2,3,4,4,4,6,7]
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(c)
items = []
for k,v in count.items():
  if v > 1:
    for item in range(v):
      items.append('*')
  else:
    items.append(k)
print(items)
```

Comment: This re-orders the list, so it doesn't work for OP's first example: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4]` -> `[1, 2, 3, '*', '*', '*', 5]`